# Logarithms / Maths with a root base or to the power of root

Tags: logarithms, roots, radicals

Greetings StackExchange!
I would like to ask this question:
How do I solve Logarithms, or just simply "Advanced Maths" (aka where these Logarithm numbers came from)

Here's the question:

1. $\log_{9\sqrt{3}}\frac{1}{81}\sqrt{3}$ (Note: the base is $9\sqrt{3}$ so it's pretty much $9\sqrt{3}^x = \frac{1}{81}\sqrt{3}$

The answer is $-\frac{7}{5}$ and I know that if it's $\log_9 \frac{1}{81}$, the result would simply be $-2$, but now that there are roots; I'm quite confused.

2. $4\sqrt{2}\log_{8\sqrt{2}} 3$ (Note: $8\sqrt{2}$ is the base so it's $8\sqrt{2}^x = 3^{4\sqrt{2}}$)

The answer is $3^\frac{5}{7}$ but I don't even know how to solve this one, so it should be $3^{4\sqrt{2}}$? which means $3^{\sqrt{32}}$, and $\sqrt{32} = 32^\frac{1}{2}$.
So it's not $3^{{32}^{\frac12}}$ right? I'm quite confused.

So where did all these answers come from and how to solve them. Please help me out! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Wellcome to MSE! It would be nice to use proper formatting.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I don't understand what the expression in the first question means. What is the meaning of $9\sqrt{3}$ ?

Comment: @Wuestenfux got it! thanks

Comment: @N.F.Taussig gotcha thanks

Comment: @MattiP. sorry, it must've been my formatting problem; I've fixed the format could you take a look?

Comment: You can use $\log_b x =\frac{\log x}{\log b}$ and try and write the $x$ and $b$ as powers of a common number (then use log laws to simplify).

Comment: The answer to the second question does not make sense since $(8\sqrt{2})^{3^{5/7}} \approx 203.8408706$, while $3^{4\sqrt{2}} \approx 500.0407493$.  Could you check the problem statement?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
$9\sqrt{3} = 3^2 \cdot 3^{1/2}= 3^{5/2}$

$\frac{1}{81}\sqrt{3} = 3^{-4} \cdot 3^{1/2} = 3^{-7/2}$

$\log_{a}{b} = c \implies a^c = b$